# Null value in json object

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net

I made a code for deserialize this [JSON](http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/394/fixtures)

First of all, I've created a class:

```
public class Self
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Soccerseason
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeTeam
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class AwayTeam
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public Self self { get; set; }
        public Soccerseason soccerseason { get; set; }
        public HomeTeam homeTeam { get; set; }
        public AwayTeam awayTeam { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public int goalsHomeTeam { get; set; }
        public int goalsAwayTeam { get; set; }
    }

    public class LastHomeWinHomeTeam
    {
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public object status { get; set; }
        public int matchday { get; set; }
        public string homeTeamName { get; set; }
        public string awayTeamName { get; set; }
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }

    public class LastWinHomeTeam
    {
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public object status { get; set; }
        public int matchday { get; set; }
        public string homeTeamName { get; set; }
        public string awayTeamName { get; set; }
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }

    public class LastAwayWinAwayTeam
    {
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public object status { get; set; }
        public int matchday { get; set; }
        public string homeTeamName { get; set; }
        public string awayTeamName { get; set; }
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }

    public class LastWinAwayTeam
    {
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public object status { get; set; }
        public int matchday { get; set; }
        public string homeTeamName { get; set; }
        public string awayTeamName { get; set; }
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }

    public class Head2head
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public string timeFrameStart { get; set; }
        public string timeFrameEnd { get; set; }
        public int homeTeamWins { get; set; }
        public int awayTeamWins { get; set; }
        public int draws { get; set; }
        public LastHomeWinHomeTeam lastHomeWinHomeTeam { get; set; }
        public LastWinHomeTeam lastWinHomeTeam { get; set; }
        public LastAwayWinAwayTeam lastAwayWinAwayTeam { get; set; }
        public LastWinAwayTeam lastWinAwayTeam { get; set; }
        public List<Fixture> fixtures { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fixture
    {
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public object status { get; set; }
        public int matchday { get; set; }
        public string homeTeamName { get; set; }
        public string awayTeamName { get; set; }
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Fixture> fixture { get; set; }
        public Head2head head2head { get; set; }
    }
```

So I made a code for parsing a request, and return a `responseText`:

```
string responseText = Parser.Request(link); //Parser is the class that perform HttpRequest
```

so far no problem.
I've declarated the object for deserialize the responseText returned:

```
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fixtures.RootObject>(responseText);
```

and next I do the foreach:

```
foreach (var fixture in obj.fixture)
{do stuff..}
```

but in `obj.fixture` I get null and I don't know why. Because all JSON is deserialized correcly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you reduce your example to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Use autogenerate classes: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: I already use it. But in this case isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key in the JSON is `"fixtures"` - it needs to match the property name of your class *exactly*. Change

```
public List<Fixture> fixture { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<Fixture> fixtures { get; set; }
```

Alternatively, you can use the [JsonProperty](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute:

```
[JsonProperty("fixtures")]
public List<Fixture> fixture { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, but I've the same problem with head2head object

Comment: There's no `head2head` in the JSON at all, nor anything that looks like it. I suggest you re-import the JSON in json2csharp.com - the JSON structure might have been changed by the providing party after you did your first import there.